# Spacing calls to API in order to avoid flooding it

Tags: javascript, rxjs6

I'm building a trading bot which sometimes requires to make multiple calls to the Exchange's API (e.g. refresh N charts after reconnect). I'd like to have these calls time-spaced so I don't end up flooding the API (I still don't want to discard any call I need to make, so debounce/throttle is not what I'm looking for). Like this:

Source: [update chart 1, update chart 2, ..., update chart N]

Observable: [update chart 1 -> wait 1 second -> update chart 2 -> wait 1 second -> ... -> update chart N]

I'd expect this observable to complete in N - 1 seconds.

How can I build such Observable?
(I'm using rxjs ^6.3.3)

Note: I was exploring the idea of having a callAPI Subject wrapping all calls to the API and delay them somehow, but I can't figure this either.

Thanks.-

**Update**: Ok, I ended up using [Bottleneck](https://github.com/SGrondin/bottleneck), like this:

```
const limiter = new Bottleneck({
  minTime: 1000
})
```

Then: `chartsToReset.map(async (chart) => await limiter.schedule(() => exchangeAPI.updateChart(chart)))`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function that has a Promise + setTimeout and a recursive function (something along the lines of):

```
var runQueries = function(source) {
  if (source.length > 0) {
    runQuery(source[0]).then(() => runQueries(source.slice(1));
  } else {
    console.log('done!')
  }
}
// this is just pseudo code...
var runQuery = function(item) {
  //var promise = new Promise
  //run code
  // setTimeout for 1000 to resolve promise
  // return promise
}
```

[Promise documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

**edit**

If the iterating function is non-destructive with the array, and you and a properties queryRunning and queries (or something) you could do (I haven't used rxjs, so you'd have to modify code slightly for that format):

```
var next = function(query) {
  // queries and queryRunning are properties on the thing doing these calls
  queries.push(query);
  if (!queryRunning) {
    runQueries();
  }
}
var runQueries = function() {
  if (queries.length > 0) {
    queryRunning = true;
    runQuery(queries.shift()).then(() => runQueries();
  } else {
    queryRunning = false;
    console.log('done!')
  }
}
// this is just pseudo code...
var runQuery = function(query) {
  var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve('complete');
    }, 1000);
  });
  //run code to handle query
  return promise1;
}
```

Comment: I was hoping for a rxjs-ish solution. Something I would be able to: next(apiRequest), next(apiRequest), next(apiRequest)... and the Observable would handle by itself.

Comment: I'm not familiar with rxjs, but I'll edit the above adding a method next() that would queue things up.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at `interval` RxJS creation function in combination with `mergeMap` operator along these lines

```
const updates = ['chart1', 'chart2', 'chart3'];

// this function simulates fetching of data for the chart
function getUpdatedChartData(chartName: string) {
  return of({chart: chartName, data: [chartName + ' 1', chartName + ' 2', chartName + ' 3']}).pipe(
    delay(Math.random() * 2000)
  )
}

const theObservableIWantToBuild = interval(1000).pipe(
  take(updates.length),
  mergeMap(i => getUpdatedChartData(updates[i]).pipe(
    tap(chartData => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(chartData, null, 3)) 
      // do something with chart data)
    }),
    map(() => updates[i])
  )),
)
```

You may see that in the simulated function `getUpdatedChartData` I have added a delay, just to make it slightly more realistic.

As a general rule, Subjects are required in a relatively limited number of cases. Any time you think you need to use a Subject, ask yourself if there is not an equivalent solution which requires simply using operators.